# NetLogo Histogram - Distribution of visits

Tags: histogram, distribution, netlogo, patch

I've a simple problem.

In my code there are some *patches* that contain food. I computed the # of visits for each one of these "resources". Now I want to put in a histogram the # of visits for each one of these *"resource-patches"* .

If I write in the GUI:

```
histogram [visits] of resource-patches
```

It plots me something strange.

This is because, usually, you put the *"x"* values in the brackets [ ] of the patches-own attribute. Instead, I want that

-in the *"x-axis"* there are the labels (for example) of the resource-patches (or their amount of food) whereas

-in *"y-axis"* I want the #of visits for each one of the resource-patches.

I'm struggling since yesterday but I can't find a solution.

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 2):

A histogram only takes in the values for the x-axis. The y-axis will always be the number of occurrences of x in the list provided. For you, it'll plot the frequency of each of yours visits.

If your visits list is [1 1 3 5 2 3 4 5]

You'll see a histogram of

```
x, y
1->2
2->1
3->1
4->1
5->2
```

I think you may want to look at another plotting tool if this is not what you want.

Comment: yeah sounds like you want something more like `ask resources-patches [ plot visits ]`

Comment: I did it.

I thought to create an invisible turtle each time that an agent goes to that resource. Then, I can count the number of this "marker" turtles on each resource.

Thank you anyway